# Cant understand theano scan applied to grad behaviour

Tags: python, theano

So here's the thing: I have to code below, and when I apply the grad wrt A everything runs fine and it computes the gradients correctly. However, if I do `wrt=i` then it gives me a DisconnectedInputError. Why is that, and how could I go about differentiating with respect to i?

```
def step(i, A):
    return A*i, i

A = T.scalar("A")
outputs, _ = theano.scan(step, sequences=T.arange(2,6), non_sequences=A)
res, i = outputs
grad = T.grad(cost=res[3], wrt=A)
func = theano.function([A],[grad, res, i])

print func(3.0)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    grad = T.grad(cost=res[3], wrt=i)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gradient.py", line 545, in grad
    handle_disconnected(elem)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gradient.py", line 532, in handle_disconnected
    raise DisconnectedInputError(message)
theano.gradient.DisconnectedInputError: grad method was asked to compute the gradient with respect to a variable that is not part of the computational graph of the cost, or is used only by a non-differentiable operator: for{cpu,scan_fn}.1
Backtrace when the node is created:
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    outputs, _ = theano.scan(step, sequences=T.arange(2,6), non_sequences=A)
```

Answer (score 0):

To differentiate wrt to i you need to declare the whole i array before the scan operation and use the whole array to calculate the gradient wrt to it.

```
i_array = T.arange(2,6)

def step(i, A):
    return A*i, i

A = T.scalar("A")
A.tag.test_value = 5.0

outputs, _ = theano.scan(step, sequences=i_array, non_sequences=A)
res, i = outputs
grad = T.grad(cost=res[3], wrt=i_array)
func = theano.function([A],[grad, res, i])

print func(3.0)
```

if you want a specific element of `i` then you should select it using an index after you calculate the grad for `i_array`